# Sourcing the data for the blog-post from markdown and JSON simultelanously

Tags: gatsby

I need some help and cannot find any workable solution.

Structure of my project looks like that:

```
    blog
        post1
            index.md
            image.jpg
            data.json
        post2
            index.md
            image.jpg
            data.json
        and so on...
```

Every generated page should source from their markdown file (and it works great due to the possibility of filtering by slug), image file (that magically also works) but I don't have any idea how to query the JSON data only from the same folder as MD and jpeg file? I cannot filter allDataJson by slug, directory path, and so on. I thought that I'll figure out something about the parents' node but the ID number doesn't tell me anything.

Any suggestions? I would be very appreciated

Comment: Why you can't filter `allDataJson` by slug?

Comment: @FerranBuireu Because that field is unavailable (it could be reached only inside the markdownRemark/allMarkdownRemark section). I've tried to use the gatsby-plugin-slug-field plugin but I cannot retrieve the slug value from the frontmatter in the gatsby-node.js (or don't know how to do it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple paths to follow to achieve it, but all of them rely on the same idea. Passing a context field based on the markdown file to filter the JSON file.

To use the slug in your JSON files, you need to create a slug node as you do with the `MarkdownRemark`.

```
exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, actions, getNode }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions;

  if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark` || node.internal.type === `postJson`) {
    let value = createFilePath({ node, getNode });

    createNodeField({
      name: `slug`,
      node,
      value,
    });
  }
};
```

According to the [schema interference](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/schema-inference/), the internal node type should be `postJson` (`MarkdownRemark` for markdown files). With the snippet above, you should be able to use the slug from the JSON if your data has the same internal structure.

Another approach is to pass via context an identifier parameter, something like the `id` or the name of the post.

```
createPage({
  path: node.fields.slug,
  component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/blog-post.js`),
  context: {
    slug: node.fields.slug,
    id: node.id // or the name
  },
})
```

Then, in your template filter by the parameter:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query($id: String!) {
    markdownRemark(id: { eq: $id} ) {
      html
      frontmatter {
        title
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried it before but it didn't worked. I was thinking that it was my fault but it turns out that I had a bug in my code. Now everything is working correctly 